# Build check query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to solve this issue with only one select. It can be easily solved with 2, but I want only one:

Imagine this simple table:

```
create table CheckTest(
    name varchar(50)
)
```

I want a query that fail (it will be inside an if statement) if there isn't any rows on the table or there is a row with name='test'

So, these are the possible scenarios:

```
--scenario 1 - no rows: should fail
truncate table CheckTest

--scenario2 - rows with value different than "test": should succeed
insert into CheckTest values ('OK')
insert into CheckTest values ('OK')


--scenario3 - 1 row with value "test" or 1 row with value "test" among other rows with value OK

insert into CheckTest values ('test')
insert into CheckTest values ('OK')
insert into CheckTest values ('OK')
```

I'm planning on using the check like this:

```
if (<check>)
    print 'fail'
else
    print 'continue'
```

Comment: Diego, you query should do what? select 'fail' or 'success' depending on the cases?

Comment: yes, its a stop condition inside a proc. I just edited the question adding this information. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible like this:

```
    if (select count(c1.name) + case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else 0 end
        from #CheckTest c
        left join #CheckTest c1 on c.name = c1.name and c1.name = 'test' )  > 0
    begin
       select 'fail'
    end
    else
    begin
      select 'success'
    end
```

Comment: works but I would like to do it with only one select. Both check on the "where" condition. I was wondering if it is possible to check a condition and if a line exist at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but I wouldn't bother.

All the ways I can think of that combine this into one `SELECT` (e.g. using `COUNT` or `DENSE_RANK`) are less efficient than two separate queries. One way below.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM   CheckTest 
              HAVING SUM(DISTINCT CASE 
                                    WHEN name = 'test' THEN 1 
                                    ELSE 2 
                                  END) = 2) 
  PRINT 'fail' 
ELSE 
  PRINT 'continue'
```